# JavaScript/HTML development with Marmalade SDK for Roku

Tags: javascript, html, marmalade, roku

Could we develop HTML5/JavaScript application for Roku with use of the Marmalade SDK instead of using the BrightScript?

Thanks a lot STeN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it is not possible, Marmalade SDK allows for Roku only C++ development:
http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/display/MD/What+do+we+support#Whatdowesupport-Targetplatforms